# Missing } inserted.for `algnewcommand ` in AMA document class

Tags: algorithmic, renewcommand, wiley-article

I am trying to prepare a paper for `Concurrency and Computation: Practice and Experience`, its latex class files could be find here: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/page/journal/15320634/homepage/la_tex_class_file.htm

I'm unable to create and use `\algnewcommand`such as: `\algnewcommand\AND{\textbf{and} }`.

```tex
\documentclass[AMA,LATO1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\newcommand\BibTeX{{\rmfamily B\kern-.05em \textsc{i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\algnewcommand\AND{\textbf{and} }
\begin{document}
\title{A demonstration of the \LaTeX\ class file for Wiley NJD Journals\protect\thanks{This is an example for title footnote.}}
\section{Introduction}\label{sec1}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State{}$x \AND y$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

Recevied error message:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/fla/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/fla/m/n' instead on input line 9.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <4.015> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 12.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OML/cmm/m/it' in size <4.015> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 12.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' in size <4.015> not available
(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 12.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
                }
l.12     \State{}$x \AND y$
```

How can I fix this error? wanted output in the algorithm line using `algnewcommand` is as follows:

x **and** y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class defines `\AND` and apparently `algorithmic` silently ignores `\algnewcommand{\AND}{...}` in this case.

Use a different name.

Beware that, with your definition, the space after `\textbf{and}` is ignored in math mode. But you shouldn't use the command in math mode anyway.

```
\documentclass[AMA,LATO1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}
\usepackage{fix-cm} % avoid warnings
\usepackage{moreverb}

\algnewcommand\algAND{\textbf{and}}

\begin{document}

\title{A demonstration of the \LaTeX\ class file for Wiley NJD 
  Journals\protect\thanks{This is an example for title footnote.}}

\section{Introduction}\label{sec1}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State $x$ \algAND\ $y$
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, the definition of `\BibTeX` is completely useless. Remove it.

In order to use the class, you need *their* version of the Lato fonts. I achieved it with no installation by adding

```
\pdfmapfile{../Lato-fonts/lato.map}
```

at the beginning of the file and calling `pdflatex` from the command line by

```
TEXINPUTS=../Lato-fonts//: VFFONTS=../Lato-fonts//: TFMFONTS=../Lato-fonts//: ENCFONTS=../Lato-fonts//: T1FONTS=../Lato-fonts//: pdflatex alper
```

where `alper.tex` is the file to process (change the name) located in the same directory as the class.

Comment: Can we also do: `$x \algAND\ y$` ?

Comment: @alper Yes, but why?

Comment: Ah in my orignal code I was keeping `\AND` inside the math-mode since it was just `\wedge`  ;

Comment: Can this solution be compiled in overleaf as well? since I am not sure I can add `TEXINPUTS=../Lato-fonts//: VFFONTS=../Lato-fonts//: TFMFONTS=../Lato-fonts//: ENCFONTS=../Lato-fonts//: T1FONTS=../Lato-fonts//:` into overlead compile setup

Comment: @alper I’m not sure. You probably have to set up a correct TeX subtree in the work directory.

Comment: It worked without a problem